# How to import file properties from windows into my application

Tags: asp.net, windows-7

I want to be able to read files' properties (size, name, date ..) for any kind of files such as (image, text, audio, video ..) from my file System (Windows) and import the properties into my web application, how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are wanting to have a web application read the properties of files stored locally on a client machine:

If that's true, then this isn't possible without using some other type of tech (ActiveX... maybe); and even then it might not be possible due to all the sandboxing around browsers.

The only way a website knows about a file on a local file system is if it is purposefully uploaded to the website by the client.

Comment: How can i upload it to the website?

Comment: @Shaza: Add a file upload control to a web page, have the user go to that web page, click the upload file button, select a file, then upload it.  Once this is done then your webserver will have a copy of that file...